# Shortest path program Python

Tags: python-3.x, input, shortest-path, is-empty

I've written the following program, and there are 2 'mistakes' which I don't know how to fix. Inputs b1, c1, d1, and e1 correspond to points and adjacent nodes.
For instance, if I give the input: A B C, this means that from point A you can travel to B and C. The input f1 corresponds to the starting and endpoint. For instance, if I give the input: A D, this means that you start at point A and want to finish at point D.

```
b1 = input() 
c1 = input()
d1 = input()
e1 = input()
f1 = input()
b = b1.split()
c = c1.split()
d = d1.split()
e = e1.split()
f = f1.split()
b_node = b[1:]
c_node = c[1:]
d_code = d[1:]
e_node = e[1:]
f_node = f[1:]

G = {b[0]:b_node, c[0]:c_node, d[0]:d_node, e[0]:e_node}

def find_path(graph, start, end, path = []):
    path = path + [start]
    newpath = []
    if start == end:
        return path
    shortest = None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath)<len(shortest):
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest
print(find_path(G, f[0], f[1]))
```

I give my program the following input

```
A B C
B A C
C B D
D
A D
```

My questions are the following:
1. My program gives an error because d_node = [] (empty). However, this is 
supposed to be so since from point D, you can't travel to any point! How can I make it run correctly?
2. Is there a way to let my program ask for a number 'N' points, and then give me N lines to give for those points all the adjacent info? I tried something of the form

```
input_list = []
x = int(input())
for i in range(x):
    input_list.append(input())
```

But couldn't make it work.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1:
You have a typo for 'd_node' as you have written 'd_code'.

2:
Try with a while-loop; continue if you enter a blank line (which will indicate that you are done entering points). Something like:

```
while True:
    i = input()
    if not i:
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a well written answer but we try to keep answers to the relevant parts only. I have edited your answer to remove the greeting.